# UnicodeDecodeError from python 2 to 3 with .decode() and sockets

Tags: python, sockets

Hello i have been working on a Python code which will flash my Arduino over WiFi and i almost have it working im so close.

The issue is it was created for Python 2 and i want it to run on the latest python 3. I added .encode and decode to places where socket sends or receives a string. and that works great up till the point where it stops reading strings and want to read a HEX string. I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\edwin\Desktop\FlashTesting\pythonFlash.py", line 258, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\Users\edwin\Desktop\FlashTesting\pythonFlash.py", line 250, in main if wait_for (cli, "\x00", MAX_TIMEOUT) [0]: File "C:\Users\edwin\Desktop\FlashTesting\pythonFlash.py", line 123, in wait_for received += cli.recv(1).decode() # .decode() is new TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0: unexpected end of data.

Normally i would reduce all the code down to the parts required but seeing as the wait_for is used throughout the code i shall paste the entire code, functions are separated by a comment line to make it easy to read. Please any help is appreciated i have been working on this since xmas eve no stop.

The error starts in the main function at the bottom of the code  when it calls wait_for and wants to read "\x00" and then it will finally call the program_process function which i think will get the same error, as you can see i added .encode() to the HEX strings there, so can you also help with with one of those so i know how to resolve that when it happens.

Thank you in advanced and have a nice new year :)

[main code that i am converting, note his indentation is shocking](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sistemasorp.es%2F2014%2F11%2F11%2Fprogramando-un-arduino-remotamente-con-el-modulo-esp8266%2F)

```
import sys 
import binascii 
import struct 
import select 
import socket 
import errno 

MAX_TIMEOUT = 500 
SUCCESS = "success" 
FAILED = "failed" 
PORT = 50000 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
''' 
Class containing the data from non-contiguous memory allocations 
''' 
class Data :
    def __init__ (self, begin, data):
        self.begin = begin 
        self.data = data 
        self.count = len (data) 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
''' 
Parameters: 
 line: The line to parse 
Returns:  
 The size of data. The address of data. The type of data. The line checksum. True if the checksum is correct, otherwise False. 
Description:  
 It parses a line from the .hex file. 
''' 
def parse_line (line): 
     ok = False 
     size = int (line [ 1 : 3 ], 16) 
     address = int (line [ 3 : 7 ], 16) 
     type = int (line [ 7 : 9 ], 16) 
     next_index = (9 + size * 2) 
     data = binascii.a2b_hex (line [9: next_index]) 
     checksum = int (line [ next_index :], 16) 

     #checking if checksum is correct 
     sum = size + (address >> 8) + (address & 0xFF) + type 
     for byte in data: 
         sum += byte # was ord(byte) removed to fix TypeError
     if ( ~ (sum & 0xFF) + 1) & 0xFF == checksum: 
         ok = True 
     return (size, address, type, data, checksum, ok) 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
''' 
Parameters: 
 chunks: An array with different chunks of data. 
 path: The path to the .hex file to read 
Returns:  
 True if the reading was successfully, otherwise False. 
Description:  
 It reads a .hex file and stores the data in memory. 
''' 
def read_hex_file(chunks, path):
    try:
        file = open (path, 'r')
    except IOError:
        print ("Hex file not loaded") 
        return False 
    line = file.readline()
    if line [0] != ':': 
        print ("The file seems to be a not valid .hex file") 
        file.close () 
        return False     
    size, address, type, data, checksum, ok = parse_line(line.strip()) 
    if not ok: 
        print ("The checksum in line 1 is wrong") 
        file.close() 
        return False 
    chunks.append(Data(address, data)) 
    # Read the other lines 
    index = 0
    count = 2
    for line in file: 
        size, address, type, data, checksum, ok = parse_line(line.strip()) 
        if not ok: 
            print ("The checksum in line", count, "is wrong") 
            file.close() 
            return False 
        if chunks [index].begin + chunks[index].count == address: 
            chunks [index].count += size
            for code in data: 
                chunks [index].data += bytes(code) # added bytes to fix TypeError
        else: 
            chunks.append(Data(address, data)) 
            index += 1
            count += 1 
    return True 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
''' 
Parameters: 
 None 
Returns:  
 The server socket 
Description:  
 It opens a server socket at the specified port and listens to connections. 
''' 
def init_server(): 
 server = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
 server.bind (('', PORT)) 
 server.listen (1) 
 return server 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
''' 
Parameters: 
 cli: The client socket 
 response: The search string 
 timeout: The maximum time in milliseconds the function can be running before a time out. 
Returns:  
 True if the string was found, otherwise False. The received string. 
Description:  
 It waits for the expected string. 
''' 
def wait_for(cli, response, timeout): 
 inputs = [cli]
 received = "" 
 milliseconds = 0 
 while milliseconds < timeout: 
     rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(inputs,[], [], 0.001) 
     if len (rlist) > 0:
         received += cli.recv(1).decode() # .decode() is new fixed TypeError
         if response in received: 
             return True, received 
     milliseconds += 1    
 return False, received 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
''' 
Parameters: 
 cli: The client socket 
 timeout: The maximum time in milliseconds the function can be running before a time out. 
 length: The number of bytes to receive. 
Returns:  
 True if the string has the required length, otherwise False. The received string. 
Description:  
 It waits for the required length of bytes. 
''' 
def return_data(cli, timeout, length = 1): 
 inputs = [cli]
 received = "" 
 milliseconds = 0 
 while milliseconds < timeout: 
     rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(inputs,[], [], 0.001) 
     if len (rlist) > 0:
         received = cli.recv(length).decode() # .decode() is new
         return True, received 
     milliseconds += 1
 return False, received 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
''' 
Parameters: 
 cli: The client socket 
Returns:  
 True if the string was found, otherwise False 
Description:  
 It waits for the acknowledge string. 
''' 
def acknowledge(cli): 
 if wait_for (cli, "\x14\x10", MAX_TIMEOUT) [0]:   #STK_INSYNC, STK_OK 
     print (SUCCESS) 
     return True 
 else: 
     print (FAILED) 
     return False
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------         
''' 
Parameters: 
 chunks: An array with different chunks of data. 
 cli: The client socket 
Returns:  
 Nothing 
Description:  
 It starts the STK500 protocol to program the data at their respective memory address. 
''' 
def program_process(chunks, cli):  # I HAVE ADDED .encode() to any strings inside cli.send IDK if they are correct ? the code has not got to this part yet....
 print ("Connection to Arduino bootloader:"), 
 counter = 0
 cli.send(("\x30\x20").encode())    #STK_GET_SYNCH, SYNC_CRC_EOP 
 if not acknowledge(cli): 
     return 
 print ("Enter in programming mode:"), 
 cli.send (("\x50\x20").encode())    #STK_ENTER_PROGMODE, SYNC_CRC_EOP 
 if not acknowledge(cli): 
     return 
 print ("Read device signature:"), 
 cli.send(("\x75\x20").encode())    #STK_READ_SIGN, SYNC_CRC_EOP 
 if wait_for (cli, "\x14", MAX_TIMEOUT) [0]:   #STK_INSYNC 
     ok ,received = return_data (cli, MAX_TIMEOUT, 3) 
     print (binascii.b2a_hex (received)) 
     if not wait_for (cli, "\x10", MAX_TIMEOUT) [0]:   #STK_INSYNC 
         print (FAILED)
         return 
 else: 
     print  (FAILED) 
     return 
 for chunk in chunks: 
     total = chunk.count 
     if total > 0:   #avoid the last block (the last line of .hex file) 
         current_page = chunk.begin 
         pages = total / 0x80 
         index = 0       
         for page in range (pages): 
             print ("Load memory address", current_page , ":"), 
             cli.send (struct.pack ((("<BHB").encode()), 0x55, current_page , 0x20))   #STK_LOAD_ADDRESS, address, SYNC_CRC_EOP 
             if not acknowledge (cli):
                 return
             print ("Program memory address:"), 
             cli.send ((("\x64\x00\x80\x46").encode()) + chunk.data [index:index + 0x80] + (("\x20").encode()))   #STK_PROGRAM_PAGE, page size, flash memory, data, SYNC_CRC_EOP 
             if not acknowledge (cli): 
                 return 
             current_page += 0x40 
             total -=  0x80 
             index += 0x80 
         if total > 0: 
             print ("Load memory address", current_page , ":"), 
             cli.send (struct.pack ((("<BHB").encode()), 0x55, current_page, 0x20))   #STK_LOAD_ADDRESS, address, SYNC_CRC_EOP 
             if not acknowledge (cli): 
                 return
             print ("Program memory address:"), 
             cli.send (struct.pack(((">BHB").encode()), 0x64, total, 0x20) + chunk.data [index:index + total] + (("\x20").encode()))   #STK_PROGRAM_PAGE, page size, flash memory, data, SYNC_CRC_EOP 
             if not acknowledge (cli): 
                 return 
 print ("Leave programming mode:"), 
 cli.send (("\x51\x20").encode())   #STK_LEAVE_PROGMODE, SYNC_CRC_EOP 
 acknowledge (cli) 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------         
def main(): 
 print ("Arduino program via ESP V1.1")
 print ("Listen to connections") 
 ser = init_server() 
 inputs = [ser]
 while True: 
     rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(inputs,[],[]) 
     for s in rlist: 
         if s == ser: 
             cli, addr = s.accept() 
             print (addr[0], "connected") 
             # It assures the connection is for programming an Arduino and not other service. 
             if wait_for (cli, "hello", 20000) [0]: 
                 cli.send(("welcome").encode()) # encode(0 is new
                 ok, received = wait_for(cli, "hex", 10000) 
                 if ok: 
                     chunks = [] 
                     print ("Read hex file", received.strip()) # prints out Read hex file Blink.ino.hex
                     if read_hex_file(chunks, received.strip()): 
                         cli.send (("ok").encode()) # encode(0 is new 
                         print ("listening for blank Serial")
                         # Wait for the byte '0' sent by Arduino after resetting 
                         if wait_for (cli, "\x00", MAX_TIMEOUT) [0]:  # CODE CURRENTLY STOPS HERE DUE TO UNICODE DECODE ERROR
                             program_process (chunks, cli) 
                     else: 
                         cli.send(("error").encode()) # encode(0 is new
             cli.close() 
             print ("Listen to connections") 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
 main()
```

Comment: This is a horrible question: random & inconsistent indentation (1-5 space indent. for blocks), and inconsistent whitespace, strings b4 def/class instead of docstrings -- it makes the code painful to read, and you've basically just dumped your code and told us "please finish my project for me". Add to that a seemingly complete lack of understanding of Unicode (hint: why can you not decode a 1-byte utf-8 string). ..also, please name the encoding to use whenever you call encode/decode. Fixing text/byte issues does not involve adding `bytes()/.encode()/.decode()` willy-nilly through your code.

Comment: There's a lot of code there, and we can't run it to test it if we don't have an Arduino or the file(s) you're trying to send. It would be much better if you could reduce it to a [mcve] that reproduces your main problem of sending & receiving bytes correctly. But anyway, doing stuff like `("\x64\x00\x80\x46").encode()` is unlikely to do what you want. That's a Unicode text string, and you're encoding it to UTF-8. That won't create the correct bytes when the string contains chars outside the ASCII range. If you want to send those bytes, use a literal `bytes` string like `b"\x64\x00\x80\x46"`.

Answer (score 0):

As thebjorn hinted at, you can't (always) decode an UTF-8 string bytewise, simply because a character can consist of multiple bytes. So, what you can do is assemble the string until it (hopefully) contains complete UTF-8 sequences, and only then decode it.

```
def wait_for(cli, response, timeout): 
 inputs = [cli]
 response = response.encode()    # Make bytes!
 received = b""                  # Make bytes!
 milliseconds = 0 
 while milliseconds < timeout: 
     rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(inputs, [], [], 0.001) 
     if len(rlist) > 0:
         received += cli.recv(1) # Do not decode yet!
         if response in received: 
             return True, received.decode() # .decode() is new fixed TypeError 
     milliseconds += 1    
 return False, received.decode() # .decode() is new fixed TypeError
```